# Flex - videoDisplay freezes for seconds when jumping to cuepoint?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, videodisplay, cue-points

Update:

I've figured out that my problem exists only when creating my project as a Flash Web Application (which is what I normally do, as I do not want the user to install the air application). If I just export the project, and try to run the .swf file then I get an error message: `Error#2148: SWF File file:///blablabla.swf cannon access local resource file:///blablabla.xml`

So what I normally do is this:
Run the .swf
Discard the error message (it then loads, but smoothing for some reason does not work).
Click File-> Create Projector (this lets me create a .exe file for this web aplication)

Now that I've done this, I can start the same presentation using the newly created .exe file. This time, I get no error, and everything is working as it should.

This is the way I've done it when making stuff like this. This project is a videoplayer with a menu, containing all the movies to play. It also implements cue points and captions for the movies.

Anyways, when using this process, I get big delays when trying to skip to cue points that are a couple minutes out in the movie. Cue points that are close to the current playtime is ok, but the further away I get the longer it takes. This is not acceptable.

If I debug it, ur run the release directly from my project folder (where I've allowed local files to be used) then it works smooth. If I create an Air application, it also works smooth..

This problem only exists if run through the generated .exe file created from a .swf file.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

What I need is:
I want to send a folder (or .zip file) to my client. He should open this, and simply run the presentation (.swf or .exe). I do not want him to install the presentation.

Below are some of my previous information:

---

This is the function when clicking a cuepoint:

```
        private function cuePointClickHandler(cTime:int, cText:String, cNr:int):Function{
            return function(e:MouseEvent):void{
                trace("Array added: " + cTime);
                videoPlayer.playheadTime=cTime;
                currentCuePointText=cText;
                changeCaption(currentCuePointText);
                currentCuePoint=cNr;
                trace("Current CuePoint NR: " + currentCuePoint + " ClickHandler!");
                updateControls();
            }
        }
```

Here is a movie showing the problem:
As you can see, when I skip close to the current time there is no problem or delay. When I click further away, there is a delay of several seconds. On slower machines this is even longer. I need it to be much smoother, at a maximum of 1 sec delay if possible.

http://screencast.com/t/QUFmKFvm

Comment: Hmm, when debugging it, it works perfectly. Skips to the cuepoint without a delay. Is this a problem I get when creating a .exe file from the flash presentation? If I dont create a .exe file, I get an errormessage on start...

Comment: Error is: Error#2148: SWF File file:///blablabla.swf cannon access local resource file:///blablabla.xml  - If I create a .exe file from this and run it, it works fine. But with the delay when seeking the video..